# Determining whether signal meets the 12 dB SINAD voltage

Tags: rf, signal, antenna, radio, receiver

The specification for the sensitivity of a certain radio receiver says: Typically 12dB SINAD NBFM for 0.15uV at 145MHz. If I understand correctly, this means that the received radio wave should have a voltage level of at least 0.15uV for the receiver to produce a signal with a quality of 12dB SINAD. I know how to calculate the signal power with the link equation, I can also calculate the electric field intensity of the EM wave, but I don't see how I can calculate the voltage level of a signal. How do I verify that my transmitted radio wave will meet this voltage requirement?

Comment: Can you calculate the power required at the antenna?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't see a way to do it, since this is the only information about the sensitivity given.

Comment: 0.15 uV at the electrical terminals of the receiver's input implies a power assuming that you know what the electrical impedance is (around 30 to 80 ohms). That power hits the antenna and comes from the transmitter via the link-loss equation. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Even though I don't know the exact impedance, I'll just assume 50 ohms then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't see how I can calculate the voltage level of a signal

Well, you know it has to be 0.15 uV RMS and, if you assume a 50 ohm impedance at the antenna electrical terminals, then you know the power (\$V^2/R\$) = 0.45 femto watts.

This will be the power transferred by the antenna to your circuit. Given that the antenna will likely have gain you'll have to factor this in to things but, the basic equation you need is the Friis link loss formula. That will tell you what power you need to transmit at over the distance between send and receive.

Answer (score 0):

With 0dBm across 50 ohms producing 0.223 volts RMS, then -120dBm across 50 ohms produces 0.223 MICROVOLTS rms.

For 0.15UVrms, you need another 3dB drop in power, or maybe 4 dB, to -124dBm.